# type error while creating confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to create a confusion_matrix but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type.
Got y_true=[False  True] and y_pred=['False' 'True'].
Make sure that the predictions provided by the classifier coincide with the true labels.
```

This is my code.

```py
predict_test = best_cat.predict(features_test)
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(target_test, predict_test),annot=True,fmt='3.0f')
plt.title('Confusion Matrix', y=1.05, size=15)
```

How can the error be solved?

Comment: Could you give us the type of the elements in `target_test` and `predict_test`?

Comment: target_test has `bool` type and predict_test has `object`. Is it possible to make one type after ml?

Comment: I've used  CatBoostClassifier model.

Comment: Could you please print the content of the `predict_test` variable? Additionally, if this is simply a list only containing `'True'` and `'False'`, you may want to do `predict_test = [eval(elt) for elt in predict_test]`.

Comment: Yes, sure. array(['False', 'True', 'False', ..., 'False', 'False', 'False'], dtype=object)

Comment: Now, this error shows up.  'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Are you sure you have tried exactly what I have written? Can you maybe show me the line raising the exception? Executing this code works here.

Comment: `predict_test = [eval(elt) for elt in predict_test]

sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(target_test, 

predict_test),annot=True,fmt='3.0f',cmap="summer")

plt.title('Confusion Matrix', y=1.05, size=15)`

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/tmp/ipykernel_93/3162553023.py in <module>

----> 1 sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(target_test, 

predict_test),annot=True,fmt='3.0f',cmap="summer")

      2 plt.title('Confusion Matrix', y=1.05, size=15)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Answer (score -1):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from sklearn import metrics

actual = numpy.random.binomial(1,.9,size = 1000)
predicted = numpy.random.binomial(1,.9,size = 1000)

confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)

cm_display = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix,
                                            display_labels = [False, True])

cm_display.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code and why it is relevant to the post? Additionally, please see the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide.